# quadrics containing the tangential variety of a curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, quadrics

Let $C\subset\mathbb{P}^r$ be a smooth nondegenerate curve (not contained in any hyperplane) of degree $d$ genus $g>0$. Consider the tangential variety $X$ of $C$: $X=\cup_{p\in C}T_pC\subset \mathbb{P^r}$. This is a surface in $\mathbb{P}^r$ which is singular along $C$.  My feeling is that $X$ can not be contained in any quadric hypersurface $Q$. Is this something reasonable to expect? A baby case is when $C$ is the rational normal curve in $\mathbb{P}^3, then  X$ is a quartic hypersurface thus not contained in any $Q$.   Any imput is welcome. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edited.**

Here is a construction of curves $C$ on a four-dimensional quadric $Q^4$ such that $TC\subset Q^4$. I am sure that this is a classical construction, (it might be I saw it previously and forgot).

**Construction.** Recall that $Q^4$ is isomorphic to $G(2,4)$ -- the Grassmanian of $2$-planes in a four-dimensional space, or equivalently to the space of in lines $\mathbb P^3$. The isomorphism is given by Plucker embedding of $G(2,4)$ to $\mathbb P^5$.

Now, take any curve $C'$ in $\mathbb P^3$ and associate to it a curve $C$ in $G(2,4)$  consisting of the collection of lines tangent to $C'$. I claim $TC\subset Q^4$ once we identify $G(2,4)$ with $Q^4$. The proof is left as an exercise.

**PS.**  I think it will be more interesting to answer the following **question**:  *For each $n$, what is the maximal $k(n)$ such that  $Q^n$ contains "non-degenerate" $k(n)$-dimensional subvariety $C^{k(n)}$ of arbitrary high degree, such that $TC^{k(n)}\subset Q^n$?* I am pretty sure that the above construction can be generalised to show that $k(n)$ tends to infinity when $n$ tends to infinity.  In fact from the very first glance it is not clear (for me) why the behaviour of such varieties $C$ should not have resemblance with algebraic Legendrian  varieties about which you can read, for  example, here : http://arxiv.org/abs/0805.3848 .

Comment: Thanks. But I think my curve is nondegenerate, which means it is not contained in any hyperplane.

Comment: The answer is completely rewritten.

Comment: Thanks. That example will work.I apprciate it. What about if I modify my question by supposing $C$ is a general curve embedded in $mathbb{P}^r$ by a general $g^r_d$? 

Comment: What is $g^r_d$? Do I understand correctly that you want to know if each non-degenerate curve $C$ in $\mathbb P^n$ can be deformed so that $TC$ is not contained in any quadric? If this is indeed the question, I have to think more about it. You might consider again to make this assumption explicit in your question (or ask a follow up question). 

Comment: Yes. By $g^r_d$ I mean a linear system of (projective) dimesion $r$ and degree $d$. This linear system maps $C$ into $\mathbb{P}^r$ (assuming it is very ample). So by general $g^r_d$ I mean exactly what you said: you could deform it in $\mathbb{P}^r$ so that $TC$ is not contained in a quadric. Thanks

Comment: @DmitriPanov: Could you give some hints how to show that for 
the curve $C \subset \mathbb{G}(1,\mathbb{P}^3)$
in your construction the tangent variety 
$TC$ is contained in $Q^4$ ($\cong \mathbb{G}(1,\mathbb{P}^3)$ under
Pluecker)? Is is possible to show it pure algebraically? Here an analytic approach which came into my mind using local parametrization of $C$ (and I'm curious if it's possible to avoid analytic tools):

Comment: we can locally
parametrize $C' \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ via
$t \mapsto v(t):=(v_1(t),v_2
(t),v_3(t)) \in \mathbb{A}^3 \subset \mathbb{P}^3 $. Then
the Gauss map $G: C' \to \mathbb{G}(1,\mathbb{P}^3), 
c \mapsto T_c C'$ is explicitely given locally as
$ v(t) \mapsto [v(t) \wedge v'(t)]$. The tangent at 
$[v(t) \wedge v'(t)]$ is given as the set
$T_{[v(t) \wedge v'(t)]}C:=\{\mathcal{l} \in \mathbb{G}(1,\mathbb{P}^3) 
\vert v(t) \in \mathcal{l} 
\subset \langle v(t), v'(t), v''(t) \rangle \} $

Comment: Now we can use the geometric fact that a line $L \subset \mathbb{P}^5$ is contained in 
Grassmannian $\mathbb{G}(1,\mathbb{P}^3) \subset \mathbb{P}^5$
iff there exist a point $p \in \mathbb{P}^3$, and 
a hyperplane $H \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ such that 
$L:= \{\mathcal{l} \in \mathbb{G}(1,\mathbb{P}^3) 
\vert p \in \mathcal{l} \subset H \}$. The tangent at 
$[v(t) \wedge v'(t)]$ is given as the set
$S:=\{\mathcal{l} \in \mathbb{G}(1,\mathbb{P}^3) 
\vert v(t) \in \mathcal{l} 
\subset \langle v(t), v'(t), v''(t) \rangle \} $. And by the fact above it is contained in Grassmannian

Comment: $\mathbb{G}(1,\mathbb{P}^3)$ and therefore in $Q^4$ by Plücker identification. So it contains any tangent line of $C$. But I would like to know if one can show this claim only with algebraic methods. Do you see how?

Answer (score 2):

There is an article of Eisenbud which discusses tangent developable surfaces to rational normal curves:

www.msri.org/~de/papers/pdfs/1992-007.pdf

It is shown in this paper that the tangent developable surface to a rational normal curve of degree 4 or greater is contained in a quadric hypersurface (see the bottom of p.13).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. What about curves of $g>0$?

Comment: I'm not aware offhand of any results on tangent developable surfaces associated to higher-genus curves.  However, the tangent developable surface to a given curve C is contained in the secant variety of C, so it might be a good idea to look into some papers on that.  

Comment: The first natural case to consider after rational normal curves is elliptic normal curves; the secant varieties of these have been studied by v.Bothmer-Hulek in

www.iag.uni-hannover.de/~bothmer/elliptic-secants.pdf

and also by T. Fisher in

http://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~taf1000/papers/hsecenc.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Your feeling is actually correct if you replace the word "tangential" with "secant" in your question. More precisely, the secant variety of any irreducible non-degenerate curve in $\mathbb{P}^n$ is not contained in any quadric.

See Corollary 2.2 in http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404900000414