# Quadric contain tangent variety of a curve in $\mathbb{P}^5$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, grassmannians, quadrics

Let $Q^4 \subset \mathbb{P}^5$ a smooth quadric over $\mathbb{C}$
which is via Pluecker map isomorphic
to Grassmannian of lines $\mathbb{G}(1,\mathbb{P}^3)$
in $\mathbb{P}^3$.

Consider following **Construction:** Let $C'$ any smooth
curve in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and $C \subset \mathbb{G}(1,\mathbb{P}^3)$
a curve obtained as image of $C'$ under
the Gauss map $ \mathcal{G}_{C'}: C' \to \mathbb{G}(1,\mathbb{P}^3)$
maps $c \in C'$ to the tangent space $T_c C' $. We assume that
$ \mathcal{G}: C' \to C$ is an isomorphism.

I would like to know how to prove pure algebraically that
$Q^4 \subset \mathbb{P}^5$ (identified with
$\mathbb{G}(1,\mathbb{P}^3)$ with Pluecker)
contains the tangent variety $TC$ of $C$. Motivation: this is claimed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/69894) and I would like to understand why this is true.

Here an idea how one could argue using analytic methods:

> **Fact:** a line $L \subset \mathbb{P}^5$ is contained in
> Grassmannian $\mathbb{G}(1,\mathbb{P}^3) \subset \mathbb{P}^5$
> iff there exist a point $p \in \mathbb{P}^3$, and
> a hyperplane $H \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ such that
> $L= \{ \mathcal{l} \in \mathbb{G}(1,\mathbb{P}^3) 
> \vert p \in \mathcal{l} \subset H \} $.

If we work in analytic setting we can locally
parametrize $C' \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ via
$t \mapsto v(t):=(v_1(t),v_2
(t),v_3(t)) \in \mathbb{A}^3 \subset \mathbb{P}^3 $. Then
the Gauss map $G: C' \to \mathbb{G}(1,\mathbb{P}^3), 
c \mapsto T_c C'$ is explicitely given locally as
$ v(t) \mapsto [v(t) \wedge v'(t)]$. The tangent at
$[v(t) \wedge v'(t)]$ is given as the set
$T_{[v(t) \wedge v'(t)]}C:=\{\mathcal{l} \in \mathbb{G}(1,\mathbb{P}^3) 
\vert v(t) \in \mathcal{l} 
\subset \langle v(t), v'(t), v''(t) \rangle \} $

And due to Fact above
$T_{[v(t) \wedge v'(t)]}C$ is contained in $\mathbb{G}(1,\mathbb{P}^3)$, and therefore in $Q^4$. Since we showed this for arbitrary tangent line of $C$ we are done

**Problem:** This argument use analytic parametrization of $C'$ I would like to avoid and
to give a different preferably pure algebraic
proof of the statement above.